# How can I filter data from relations in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-resource

I have 3 tables business, service , service_venues. I need services of business having service_name = $search and and get venues of selected services. I am using services and resources method.

When there is search_keyword the data is not filtered. But other conditions are working.
How can I fix this?

In business model

```
public function businessServices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BusinessService::class);
    }
```

in businessService model

```
 public function businessServiceVenues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BusinessServiceVenue::class);
    }
```

In service file

```
public function getServices($business){
       $businessservices =  $business->with(['businessServices'=> function ($q){
            $q->where('business_services.service_name', 'like', '%'.request()->search_key.'%');
        }
        ])->first();        
        return  new servicesResource($businessservices);
    }
```

In service resource

```
$services = $this->businessServices()
        ->with(['businessServiceStaffs','businessServiceVenues'])
        ->when(request()->filled('venue_ids'), function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->whereHas('businessServiceVenues', function($q1) use($request) {
                $q1->whereIn('venue_id',$request->venue_ids);
            });
          })
        ->when(request()->filled('staff_id'), function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->whereHas('businessServiceStaffs', function($q1) use($request) {
                $q1->where('staff_id','=',$request->staff_id);
            });
          })
        ->get();
```

Comment: have you tried this 
 $businessservices =  $business->whereHas('businessServices',function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $q){
            $q->where('service_name', 'like', '%'.request()->search_key.'%');
        }
        ])->first();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
$businessServices = $business->businessServices()
            ->with(['businessServiceStaffs', 'businessServiceVenues'])
            ->when(request()->filled('search_key'), function ($q) {
                $q->where('business_services.service_name', 'like', '%' . request('search_key') . '%');
            })
            ->when(request()->filled('venue_ids'), function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('businessServiceVenues', function ($q) {
                    $q->whereIn('venue_id', request('venue_ids'));
                });
            })
            ->when(request()->filled('staff_id'), function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('businessServiceStaffs', function ($q) {
                    $q->where('staff_id', '=', request('staff_id'));
                });
            })
            ->get();
```